# How many bits are required for binary representation of 64G?

Tags: binary, hex, bit

So we are doing an assignment dealing with hexadecimal, binary and decimal conversion, and I got this question. I have no idea where the G is coming from, I know hexadecimal does not include a G. Is this a trick question with no answer, or does the G stand for something that I don't know?

Here is the whole question.

5-  How many bits are required for binary representation of 64G? Use the shortest way to find the answer. Explain.

Comment: Have you considered asking the instructor?

Comment: Yeah, I have not gotten a response in 2 days...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the G stands for Giga, you can assume 64GB or 64Gb, 64 Gigabytes and 64 Gigabits respectfully, meaning that the question is missing a B or b.

Let's just review one thing first before I give a complete answer:

```
1 bit = 8 bytes
1024 bytes = 1 Kilobyte (2^10 = 1024)
1024 Kilobyte = 1 Megabyte
1024 Megabyte = 1 Gigabyte
```

If it is bits then the calculation should be something like:

```
64 Gigabits = 64 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 68719476736 bits
```

If it is Bytes then:

```
64 Gigabytes = 64 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 8 = 549755813888 bits
```

Comment: This is what I figured as well, I just want to be sure that a single G did not have a meaning I didn't know about.

Comment: If there is only one G normally it refers to GB, but only your teacher can answer that.